# Doubt about the derivation for the formula of time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time-dilation

If I imagine a photon being released from the plate below as soon as the plates start moving, shouldn't the photon hit the opposite plate a bit behind the point where it would have hit if the plates were stationary, how does the photon move with the two plates?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the primed frame, the pulse of light was emitted at an angle as depicted. Angles Lorentz-transform generally as (see: [wiki: Abberation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberration_(astronomy)#Relativistic_explanation))

1. $$ \theta' = \tan^{-1}{\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\gamma(v/c + \cos{\theta})}} $$

which in our case with a right angle between the pulse and the velocity in the unprimed frame simplifies nicely to:

2. $$ \theta' = \tan^{-1}{\frac{c}{\gamma v}} $$

Examine the diagram geometrically and pick the same trigonometric function, the tangent of the angle is the opposite leg ($L$) over the adjacent leg ($.5 v \Delta t'$), so:

3. $$\theta' = \tan^{-1}{\frac{L}{.5 v \Delta t'}} $$

Substitute $\Delta t' = \gamma \Delta t$ and $\Delta t = 2L/c$ and simplify to obtain eqation 2 from equation 3.